# Grayscale array plot?

Tags: plotting, color

how to draw the grayscale arrays using the ArrayPlot command of a square of the size of 40 by 40 pixel, with the values of 100.

```
ArrayPlot[Table[100, {x, 40}, {y, 40}], Mesh -> True, 
PixelConstrained -> {40, 40}]
```

I am using the above code but I am not seeing a change in the gray scale for 0.1 or any other values except 0.

And I also want to change the values in each line from 1 to 40. So, I can see the change in grayscale.

Comment: Something like `ArrayPlot[ConstantArray[Subdivide[39], 40]]`? (For comparison, look at `Image[ConstantArray[Subdivide[39], 40]]`.)

Comment: `ArrayPlot` uses the value you specified to color that cell.
`Table[100, {x, 40}, {y, 40}]` will generate a matrix which all of its value is `100`, so you should not see any changes.

Comment: Perhaps `ArrayPlot[Table[0.8, {x, 40}, {y, 40}], Mesh -> True, 
 PixelConstrained -> {40, 40}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> GrayLevel]` or `ArrayPlot[Table[0.8, {x, 40}, {y, 40}], Mesh -> True, 
 PixelConstrained -> {40, 40}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[1-#]&)]`

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

```
t = Table[x y, {x, 40}, {y, 40}];
ArrayPlot[t]
```

[image]